# Google Chrome Extension typeError: chrome.bookmarks.import is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello I would like to write a Chrome Extension that exports my favorites to an HTML-file.
I call the function as described in the [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/#method-export) as follows:

```
chrome.bookmarks.export(() => {
    
})
```

But I get the error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chrome.bookmarks.import is not a function
```

How do I access this function to export my favorites to an HTML-file?

Comment: Did you list "bookmarks" in the "permissions" fields of your [extension manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/bookmarks/#manifest)?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer yes I have bookmarks added in the manifest